# The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Get Data Fragment for Accelerometer Sensor

Tags: android, fragment, accelerometer, findviewbyid

I'm doing my project for getting data by acceleometer sensor in android platform. I'm having error codes in the 3 last line codes. Exactly the error is  the findViewById is not for get data fragment. so, how I can use findviewbyId in Fragment for getting data accelerometer sensor?many thanks for the answer :)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;


public class GetDataFragment extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

//definisi variabel-variabel
//Sensor accelerometer;
private Activity parent;
TextView koordinatX;
TextView koordinatY;
TextView koordinatZ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_data, container, false);
}

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor sensor;
//TextView koordinatX;


    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     parent = getActivity();


    sensorManager = (SensorManager) parent.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);


    koordinatX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinatx);
    koordinatY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinaty);
    koordinatZ = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinatz);


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must inflate your `Views` in `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_data, container, false);
    koordinatX = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coordinatx);
    koordinatY = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coordinaty);
    koordinatZ = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coordinatz);
    return rootView;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just did your suggestion just now like the code below 

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_data, container, false);
  
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_data,container,false); //line 6
  koordinatX = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coordinatx);
  koordinatY = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coordinaty);
  koordinatZ = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coordinatz);
  return rootView;
  
 }
the error is unreachable code in line 6

Comment: Copy-paste the code from scratch as it is, you've made a mistake.

Comment: oke I just did it, but still error in public void onCreate that contain : koordinatX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinatx);
  koordinatY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinaty);
  koordinatZ = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinatz);