# Android - Replacing fragment and change its TextViews

Tags: android, android-fragments, settext

I'm trying to change the text of a TextView inside a fragment that replace an old fragment in the same activity.

I already searched for existing answers to this question, and I found these two, but the solutions doesn't seems to work for me:

[Dynamically change TextView in Fragment (public void processMessage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361762/dynamically-change-textview-in-fragement-public-void-processmessage)

[Change TextView inside Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539029/change-textview-inside-fragment)

The problem is that when I create a method to set the text of a TextView inside my new fragment, it doesn't find the view I'm searching.

Here's the code of the fragment that have to replace the old one:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment_sbagliato extends Fragment {

public Fragment_sbagliato() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sbagliato, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}

public void myNewText(String[] text){
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
    textView.setText(text[0]);
}

}
```

To be specific, the error is "answer cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a compilation error - R.id.answer isn't defined. This usually happens because the java source file imports the platform "android.R" resource class instead of your app's specific "R" resource class or because there's an error in the XML resource file which is causing a problem when generating the resources.

Comment: Oh wow, I forgot to copy the answer TextView in the fragment, thanks for reminding me of these distraction problems. Btw now I get another error, that is "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Fragment_sbagliato", but all the needed imports for this method are already imported in the class

Comment: You can use `getView().findViewById()` to search the root view (or `getActivity().findViewById()`)

Comment: Ok, solved with this, thank you anyway!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919182/the-method-findviewbyidint-is-undefined-for-the-type-get-data-fragment-for-acc

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling method myNewText ?
your fragment view will not be created as soon as you commit a fragment transaction. The best way is to , pass your answer string array as fragment argument, and then overirde onActivityCreated method of the fragment call findviewbyId set data

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem was just that after modifying the fragment, I forgot to re-insert the "answer" TextView, sorry for wasting you time and thanks again